# Excel Formula return the value beside the latest date

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to return the Card used to B2 based on the table to the right.

This returned value should be of the latest date(column G), and the cell to the left of the date should not be blank. If it is blank, return the next latest value.

I have this formula but I want it to return Bank B onto B3 instead of "0" how do i go about achieving this?

```
   =INDEX($F$2:$F$7, MATCH(A2 & MAX(IF($E$2:$E$7=A2,$G$2:$G$7)), $E$2:$E$7 & 
  $G$2:$G$7, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: It's funny but I just marked a VLOOKUP with criteria question as a duplicate not more than 56 minutes ago. Please show your work.

Comment: Im trying to use Index match with max and ifand function but i dont seem to understand how it works.

Comment: [Edit] your post to show what you HAVE tried so far, and the error returned.

Comment: I'm sorry. What part of 'Please show your work.' wasn't clear?

Comment: @Olly, if you put *edit* in square brackets, (e.g. `[edit]`) you get a shorthand link to editing the question e,g, [edit].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this, you need a complex array formula:

`=INDEX($F$2:$F$7;MATCH(MAX(IF(IF($F$2:$F$7<>"";$E$2:$E$7)=A2;$G$2:$G$7))&A2;$G$2:$G$7&$E$2:$E$7;0);1)`

> **IMPORTANT!:** Because it is an array formula, you will need to type it
>   as usual, and then, instead of pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> press
>   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

I've tested in my Excel and got this:

[image]

Comment: just a question, will this work if used on a pivot table?

Comment: You mean to create a  Pivot Table linked to this data? Yes, it will work. If you mean to use this formula inside the Pivot Table itself, as far as I know, you cannot use formulas in Pivot tables, not even with Calculated Fields. (at least in Excel 2007, the version I got)

Answer (score 0):

Try INDEX/AGGREGATE with a nested AGGREGATE for the conditional MAXIFS (assuming you don't have MAXIFS).

[image]